# trouble pasting a Word equation into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to paste equations from Word into Excel 2007. The following Excel VBA code achieves this:

```
Sub ExpandEqn(MyText As String)

Dim appWd As Word.Application
Dim docWd As Word.Document
Dim objRange As Word.Range
Dim objEq As OMath

Set FindActiveCell = Application.ActiveCell
GetRange = CStr(FindActiveCell.Address())
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
NextActiveCell = CStr(FindActiveCell.Address())

Set appWd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
appWd.Visible = False
Set docWd = appWd.Documents.Add
Set objRange = docWd.Application.Selection.Range
objRange.Text = MyText
docWd.Application.Selection.OMaths.Add objRange
docWd.Application.Selection.OMaths.BuildUp
docWd.Application.Selection.WholeStory
docWd.Application.Selection.Copy

Range(NextActiveCell).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)",Link:=False,DisplayAsIcon:=False

appWd.Quit (False)
Set docWd = Nothing
Set appWd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the pasted equation is the width of the Word document with lots of empty space e.g.

[image]

Is there a way to paste in just the equation without the space? It works fine if the image is pasted as a bitmap, but I need it to be an enhanced metafile.

Many thanks and best wishes.

Comment: As you code already works, just resize the Picture from within the Excel app.

Comment: Why not create the equation directly in Excel? It has the same Insert Equation capability and object model as Word...

Comment: Thanks for that Gary's Student. Unfortunately it does not resize nicely. The whole picture, including the space, resizes. In any case, I need it to be pasted correctly programmatically if possible.

Comment: Thanks for that Cindy. Unfortunately, I do not think Excel 2007 has this capability.

Comment: [equation editor](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Equation-Editor-in-Excel-2007-for-Windows-771c7a8b-4b3d-4ab8-982a-8ab22f1212ce) for excel 2007

Comment: Thanks gtwebb. I really need to convert text into an equation, then display it in Excel 2007. I do not think this is possible with Equation 3.0, especially not programmatically.

Comment: One possibility is changing the margins in Word so that they exactly fit the equation before it is copied. Unfortunately I cannot see a way to find the width of the equation object programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after my discussion with you I came to a better understanding of what you want.  I believe this should resolve the issue.  Thanks for your patience.

```
Sub ExpandEqn(MyText As String)
    Dim appWd As Word.Application
    Dim docWd As Word.Document
    Dim objRange As Word.Range
    Dim objEq As OMath
    Dim FindActiveCell As Range
    Dim intColumnWidth As Integer
    Dim intRowHeight As Integer

    Set FindActiveCell = Application.ActiveCell
    GetRange = CStr(FindActiveCell.Address())
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    NextActiveCell = CStr(FindActiveCell.Address())

    Set appWd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    appWd.Visible = False
    Set docWd = appWd.Documents.Add
    Set objRange = docWd.Application.Selection.Range
    objRange.Text = MyText
    docWd.Application.Selection.OMaths.Add objRange
    docWd.Application.Selection.OMaths.BuildUp
    docWd.Application.Selection.WholeStory
    docWd.Application.Selection.Copy

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    NextActiveCell = CStr(FindActiveCell.Address())
    Range(NextActiveCell).Select
    intColumnWidth = Range(NextActiveCell).ColumnWidth
    intRowHeight = Range(NextActiveCell).RowHeight
    docWd.Application.Selection.Columns.Width = intColumnWidth
    docWd.Application.Selection.Rows.Height = intRowHeight

    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

End Sub
```

Essentially what I did here was to the current width and height of the cell before pasting the item and then executing the paste.  The object will then be pasted at the same size as the cell you are pasting into it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately this code does not paste as an equation, just the text "3x^2+5" for example. I really need it to be a properly formatted equation with fraction lines, square roots etc.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue if you use character sets that allowed that.  Did you try xlPasteFormula?

Comment: Thanks again @Karlomanio. I really need the equation as an image. Also some equations would be very hard or impossible to display as just text - for example: [link](https://labs.vmware.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/VMW-SS-MARVASTI-EQUATION-2.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried formatting the paste object after pasting it?  I could see if I could help you with that if you like.

Comment: I have tried a few things, but nothing has worked that could be achieved programmatically (e.g. resizing the Word borders manually so that they exactly fit the equation before it is copied). I would be very grateful for anything you can find - many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution - but it is pretty horrible:

- Create the equation in word and copy it to the clipboard.
- Paste it into Excel as a bitmap, which works fine - no extra space.
- Get the width of the bitmap, then delete it.
- Back into Word, resize the borders to that width and re-copy the equation.
- Back into Excel, paste as enhanced metafile

This can all be done programmatically, but there must be a better way!

Comment: I thought you wanted it as a bitmap.  Why are you using an enhanced metafile?  Could you use the width of your columns before inserting?  That could you save you an extra step...  Sorry, I'm late in getting back to you.

Comment: Thanks @Karlomanio - I did say I needed an enhanced metafile. This is because the image may need to be resized and/or printed to high quality. I'm not sure what you mean by 'use the width of your columns', please note that all of this needs to be done programmatically. Thanks again for your continued help and advice.